# ssh "packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe" -- where is the source code?

Tags: openssh

We got a client ssh to a remote server showing this error.  It has always been running fine, no firewall rules change either.  When an ssh session is idled over the weekend, it is still connected.  Just some times when we 'less' and shift-F on a file for couple of hours, it shows this error.

I'm not trying to solve this problem in this post.  We want to look at the ssh source code to figure out what is going on.  On Centos 7, I downloaded `openssh-7.4p1-21.el7.src.rpm`, and extracted `openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz`.  'grep' through source code and found 'packet_write_wait' function.  But curiously, "Broken pipe" (or -i on each word separately) is not found in all the .h and .c files.  Where is that error text coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a copy of the OpenSSH source code [in github](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable). The `packet_write_wait` function is in [opacket.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_4_P1/opacket.c#L288):

```
void
packet_write_wait(void)
{
    int r;

    if ((r = ssh_packet_write_wait(active_state)) != 0)
        sshpkt_fatal(active_state, __func__, r);
}
```

It calls another function to write the packet. If that fails, it calls `sshpkt_fatal`. `sshpkt_fatal` is in [packet.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_4_P1/packet.c#L2077), and its job is to print an error message and then exit.

```
/*
 * Pretty-print connection-terminating errors and exit.
 */
void
sshpkt_fatal(struct ssh *ssh, const char *tag, int r)
{
    switch (r) {
    case SSH_ERR_CONN_CLOSED:
        logdie("Connection closed by %.200s port %d",
            ssh_remote_ipaddr(ssh), ssh_remote_port(ssh));
[...code removed...]
            /* FALLTHROUGH */
    default:
        logdie("%s%sConnection %s %.200s port %d: %s",
            tag != NULL ? tag : "", tag != NULL ? ": " : "",
            ssh->state->server_side ? "from" : "to",
            ssh_remote_ipaddr(ssh), ssh_remote_port(ssh), ssh_err(r));
    }
}
```

The message that you're asking about is handled by the default case. The last argument, which provides the text after the colon, is provided by calling [`ssh_err`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssherr.c#L22):

```
const char *
ssh_err(int n)
{
    switch (n) {
    case SSH_ERR_SUCCESS:
        return "success";
    case SSH_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "unexpected internal error";
[...etc...]
```

The `ssh_err` case that you're interested in is this one:

```
case SSH_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR:
        return strerror(errno);
```

In short, the "Broken pipe" message comes from the standard library function [`strerror`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strerror.html), which converts error numbers to standard error messages.

The [list of standard error codes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) indicates that "Broken pipe" is associated with the EPIPE error.

Comment: Ah yes, I've looked couple of time through the switch but still missed the case of stderror(errno).  Thank you!